# De Broglie wavelength of a photon

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, wavelength

The de Broglie wavelength of a photon and the wavelength of its corresponding electromagnetic wave are numerically the same. Is this just a coincidence and the two waves are different or is the de Broglie wave of a photon the electromagnetic wave corresponding to it?

Answer (score 1):

Not a coincidence. The Planck relations for photons and the de Broglie wavelength are the same equation:

$E = hf = h c/ \lambda = pc \to \lambda = h/p$

Plugging in $p = \gamma m v \approx mv$ for $v \ll c$ gets you the de Broglie wavelength of massive particles.